# Inner Exception: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

whenever i enter usename and password it throws an exception. but when i run it individually it runs perfectly.

Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Code

```
private void testing()
{
    try
    {
        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

            var loading_Win = new Loading_Window();

            loading_Win.Show();

            loading_Win.Closed += (s, ex) =>
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background);

            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }));

        // Set the apartment state
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        // Make the thread a background thread
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;

        // Start the thread
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

this is the loading window cs

```
public partial class Loading_Window : MetroWindow
{
    public Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int intIteration = 1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    public Loading_Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitTimer();

        this.Closing += Loading_Window_Closing;
    }

    private void Loading_Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Process[] pro = null;
        //try
        //{
        //    pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("LeanPims");
        //    pro[0].Kill();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{ }
        //Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }

    public void InitTimer()
    {            
        intIteration = 0;
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 300; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        intIteration += rnd.Next(1, 8);
        label1.Content = intIteration.ToString() + " %";

        try
        {
            if (intIteration >= 100)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1 = null;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

this is the loading window xaml

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <Grid Height="500" Width="700" >
        <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="300" Height="350" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images\Loading1.gif"  />
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="298,228,0,0" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Fill="White"/>
        <Label Content="" x:Name="label1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="327,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#FF837F7F" Background="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="c1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="406" Margin="112,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="481"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' threw an exception.

Comment: Which line exactly that throws the exception, also what does really the Loading_Window do?

Comment: Loding_Win.Show(); throws an exception and loading windows is a circular progress bar.....its a Gif file which looks like a loading window.

Comment: That's strange... I've tested your code with a dummy `Window` and it seems perfectly fine. Moreover it's the very same principle that I use in my released LOB WPF application too where this exact code does a good job. Please double-check the stack trace of the `InnerException`. Is `.Show()` the real cause or is there perhaps another `InnerException` in the `InnerException`? Can you post the contents of the `Loading_Window`? There must be something very specific going on in there.

Comment: i have edited the question now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to set `label1.Content`.

You either have to use a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` instead or you have to invoke the Dispatcher manually using:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => label1.Content = intIteration.ToString() + " %");
```

The same is true for all other UI-related calls.

If you don't want to use a `DispatcherTimer` then you have to do this as well:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
```

But there have to be even more UI-related statements because your `XamlParseException` states that `Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' threw an exception` and I don't see a single `Button` in the code you posted.

So check if there are any other UI-related calls and invoke them using the right `Dispatcher`. (Especially pay attention that you don't use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` in your `Loading_Window` if you have multiple `Dispatchers` in your application. Just use `Dispatcher` or `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` in that case.)

And last but not least I'm pretty sure that there is yet another `InnerException` in the `XamlParseException` that says `Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' threw an exception`. Please check that as well. It could be another cause or it just could be the same as above. Either it is in the constructor of a control that inherits from `Button` or it is probably somewhere in the XAML.